# Zustand setState outside of component doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, zustand

My store is set inside store.js as all the other Zustand stores:

```
const retryStore = create(set => ({
    retry_n: 0,
    setGRetry: (retry_n) => set(state => ({
        ...state,
        retry_n,
    })),
}));
export { retryStore };
```

inside my @/utils/get.js file I try to update the number by 1, using setState as:

```
    const retry_n = retryStore.getState().retry_n
    const xxx = xxxStore.getState().xxx
    const xxxx = xxxxStore.getState().xxxx

    var j=0;
    const maxretry = 20;

    const myFetch = async () => {
        try {
            let url = `...`

            while(j < maxretry){

                console.log('while try n:',j)     // 1,2,3... ecc
                console.log('get.js retry_n:',retry_n)  // always 0
                
                if (isItRetry){            // TRUE
                    retryStore.setState({ retry_n: retry_n + 1})
                    console.log('playThis retry_n now:',retry_n)    // always 0
                }else{
                    ...
                }

                if (a != b){ ... return }

                j++
            }
            etc...
```

shouldn't this increment by 1 each loop? why is always 0? I use other stores the same way in the same file and all work but this one.

Comment: You declared `retry_n` variable as `const`, so it will stay the same forever, and in every iteration you set the global `retry_n` to be the same value of `retry_n`+1. Try changing it to `var` instead.

Comment: that declaration is correct following Zustand doc https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#readingwriting-state-and-reacting-to-changes-outside-of-components also if that was true I wouldn't be able to change xxx and xxxx stores as well, but I'm changing those further below in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to update state with this:

```
const setRetryState = retryStore(store => store.setState)
setRetryState({retry_n: retry_n + 1})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).